# Is there a Python equivalent of PHP's $_GET[] and $_POST[]?

Tags: python, apache2

I'm using python and apache2.

I'd like to write a script called test.py that when accessed at http://example.com/test.py?foo=bar, prints the string 'bar'

I'm thinking it should be like this:

```
def index(req):

    return idontknow.foo
```

The idontknow.foo is the part I'm asking about.

Comment: *How* are you using Apache2? How are you serving your app? Python is not a web-specific language like PHP, it needs some interface with Apache. What are you using (and why didn't you look in the documentation for that library?)

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific library that I'm using.  I'm not importing anything.  The code is literally as minimal as it looks above.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall Then try `import os` and `print(os.environ())` and see if what you're looking for is in there. perhaps even `sys.argv` can assist you.

Comment: Python is not PHP, and it doesn't work the same way.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yup.  Hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fieldstorage in cgi` for ex :

if the url is :

```
hello_get.py?first_name=ABC&last_name=XYZ

#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')
```